# If exit array, enter from the other side

Tags: c#, c++, math

How can I do this for example if I have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 array and I am in 4th position (number 5) and if you have to move it to the right 4 positions you should be in position 1 (number 2). The same goes with negative numbers but you move to left. I guess there is a need of while(true) loop?

Comment: Can you provide us with what you have tried thus far?

Comment: Make a method that returns you an index. For positive something like `int index(int i, int n) {return i%n; }`

Comment: You can overlad [] operator for your container and take @Valentin s suggestion into consideration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets assume `i` is the index and `n` is the size of the array. 
For positive `i` the needed index = `i%n`
For negative `i` `i%n` returns negative residue, so the needed index is `n+i%n`

You can use

```
int index(int i, int n) {
   return i%n < 0 ? n + (i%n) : i%n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your index like this:

```
var newIndex = (index + 4) % 7;
```

So the fourth position becomes (4+4) % 7 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Always clearer with named functions and followable code path instead of voodoo one liners that work

```
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var testData = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

        Assert.AreEqual(2, TraverseCircularArray(testData, 5, 3));
        Assert.AreEqual(6, TraverseCircularArray(testData, 2, -4));
    }

    private int TraverseCircularArray(int[] array, int currentIndex, int interval)
    {
        var i = array[currentIndex];

        if (currentIndex + interval < 0)
            i = array[array.Length + (interval + currentIndex)];
        else if (currentIndex + interval >= array.Length)
            i = array[currentIndex - interval - 1];
        else
            i = array[currentIndex + interval];

        return i;
    }
```

Comment: here purpose is not to give code of answer but giving him advice to solve his problem by himself. This way asker can learn robustly by solving the problem himself.